# Ошибка в create index. Firebird 1.5

Tags: firebird

```
SET TERM ^;

SET SQL DIALECT 3^

SET NAMES WIN1251^

SET CLIENTLIB 'fbclient.dll'^

CREATE DATABASE '127.0.0.1:test.fdb'
USER 'SYSDBA' PASSWORD 'masterkey'
PAGE_SIZE 16384
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET WIN1251^

CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(127) COLLATE PXW_CYRL NOT NULL
)^

CREATE INDEX IDX1 ON TABLE_1 (NAME)^
```

На последней команде получаю ошибку:

> This operation is not defined for system tables.
>   unsuccessful metadata update.
>   key size too big for index IDX1.

Почему так происходит? У Firebird 1 и 1.5 ограничение на размер индекса 252 байта. Используется однобайтовый charset. Почему 127 символов не влазят в 252 байта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В порядке PXW_CYRL разные регистры имеют одинаковый вес.
Алфавитный порядок для кириллицы будет выглядеть так: аАбБвВгГдД...яЯ

COLLATE WIN1251 используется 1 байт для представления символа и его порядка, но в PWX_CYRL это 3 байта.

Возможно поможет изменение COLLATE на WIN1251 в поле NAME